# CakePhp Select query..using findall()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**code**

```
$records = $this->User->find('all', array( 
'conditions' => array('User.email' => 'prakashgupta3@gmail.com')));
```

**database**

```
database fields(id,username,email,img_name,password)
 table name is signup
```

This is my select query..using find all in cakephp..the query is running fine.

Under this i want to access the row in the database where email='prakashgupt3@gmail.com.

it is clearly defined above and easily understood by cakephp users. I'm new to cakephp right now.

Just tell me how to display the data which is stored in the record variable, coz record is returning an array,,when i print $record then the output is "Array"...
Your replies are mostly welcome.
                                     ....Thankyou.....

Comment: thanks >Pragnesh...but please tell me the answers....

Comment: did you try to access like this `$records['User']['email']`

Comment: Yup i tried this...when i try to echo $records['User']['email']..then again the ouput is "Undefined index: User "... :-(...Any other solutions..thnks for ur reply again..Man.

Comment: when you expect only one record (as should be the case with a `user email`, then you can use `find('first', ...)`, which will return an array in the format `$var['Model']['field']`, preventing the need to loop through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cakephp `find('all')` will return array like this

```
   Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ModelName] => Array
            (
                [id] => 83
                [field1] => value1
                [field2] => value2
                [field3] => value3
            )

        [AssociatedModelName] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [field1] => value1
                [field2] => value2
                [field3] => value3
            )

    )
)
```

so you need to access it like `$records[0]['User']['email'], $records[1]['User']['email']... $records[key]['User']['email']`

also

```
foreach ($records as $k => $v) {
       echo $v['User']['email'];
    }
```